# How to resolve the docker error" Syntax error: "(" unexpected "

Tags: selenium, docker, gradle

I am new to docker and I am trying to build a docker file for my selenium code (uses gradle)to send it over to devOps for integrating in pipeline . I am able to build the image but when I try running the image i get the following error 
 "File name too long
    /code/executables/chromedriver.exe: 4: /code/executables/chromedriver.exe: Syntax error: "(" unexpected" . Please find the docker file and main class code below

The same code is working fine when i run outside of docker env .

executables is a project folder under which chromedriver.exe is placed

docker file code :

```
FROM selenium/standalone-chrome
FROM gradle
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
CMD gradle build --info
```

Main java class code where the error i think is originating from :

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
dc = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
dc.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","./executables/chromedriver.exe");
Drivers.driver = new ChromeDriver(dc);
Drivers.driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Selenium but familiar with Docker. Your Docker image is based on Linux but `./executables/chromedriver.exe` looks like a Windows binary. If so, that won't work. Related to this, your container's working directory is `/code` (this is why the error is from `/code/executables/chromedriver.exe`, the current directory `.`. being replaced with `/code`). I assume this binary isn't available (even if it were a Linux binary) unless it's `ADD`ed and available from your local working directory.

Comment: Could you please suggest me what should i try ? should i try removing ADD ?and try ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unfamiliar with Selenium and unable to help. Have a look at this link to Selenium's Docker images: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium